# How to spawn prefab from instantiated object Mirror Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-mirror

I'm new to Unity's Mutliplayer system and I don't really know how to do a specific thing.

Players can have multiples weapons. When the player change weapon, an object is instantied from the resources only client-side. The thing is that a weapon needs to spawn object(s), with reference(s) and use them after. I made all weapons inherit from NetworkBehaviour and tried to call [Command] methods or [ClientRpc] method but get many errors or it just worked for one player.

The only thing I did well was to take a weapon code and execute it from a player script but move all the code from all weapons to a script on the player doesn't make any sense.
I know now that I can't call [Command] from my weapons so how I'm supposed to make those things work with the server ?

Comment: Take a look at the [Mirror Authority documentation](https://mirror-networking.gitbook.io/docs/guides/authority).
Just instantiating objects won't work because mirror expects you to use the `Spawn` function. Basically you spawn an object on the server and then give the respective client authority over said object to acutally call functions which are synchronized between all clients.